# Performance : computing in Haskell using Vector (a,b) versus Map a b

Tags: haskell

I want to play around with text statistics, comparing texts pairwise by looking at relative frequencies of words in them (typically by computing the sum of absolute values of differences). This is O(n^2) in the number of texts, so precomputation within each text is ok. My question is about how to represent such statistics. I have tried two ways:

- `Vector (T.Text,Double)` sorted by hand (during precomputation), and given two such vectors, compute the sum by a recursive function. Kind of `zip` keeping track of alignment of the first element of the pair, followed by a `fold`.
- `Map T.Text Double` and then cooking up the same thing using `mergeWithKey (\k x y -> Just abs (x-y)) id id` with a `foldl' (+) 0` on top.

The second way is much more expressive, because a `Map` is essentially what text statistics really are, and the code is much shorter. But on the other hand the `Vector` is about 3 times faster, at the cost of a lot of verbosity, and somehow it feels wrong, like a naive implementation of a `Map`. Of course it misses all the fancy insert / update / whatever, but I don't need that.

Am I missing something here, like a third data structure that would be better for the task?

Comment: BTW, third option would be to number the words, have a `Map T.Text Int` doing that, and storing statistics as an `Array` (or possibly `Vector Double`) indexed by that. But the total vocabulary of the union of all the texts is much larger that that of each text individually, so it ends up being worse.

Comment: The real question is what parts of the program are causing it to be slow.  Map may be faster at insertion/update/delete, but _much_ slower at performing the sums and other math.  Can you benchmark your code to determine where the slowdowns are?  Alternatively, something like `Map Text (Vector Double)` might be useful if you're keeping stats on each word individually.  Just some ideas to think about

Comment: Perhaps the third structure you're looking for is a trie.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have two documents, both with `O(m)` words. Then both your implementations take `O(m log m)` time to compare the documents.

```
Sorting document 1 into a Vector (Text, Double) ~ O(m log m)
Sorting document 2 into a Vector (Text, Double) ~ O(m log m)
stepping through vector 1 and 2 ~ O(m)
total: O( m log m )

Storing document 1 in a Map Text Double ~ O(m log m)
Storing document 2 in a Map Text Double ~ O(m log m)
stepping through map 1 and map 2 ~ O(m log m)
total: O( m log m )
```

So your solutions are asymptotically equivalent, but this doesn't mean that both should have the same runtime.  Testing against real data to see which has the smaller coefficient is the work of profiling, and is entirely appropriate at this point. The Vector solution may be less elegant, but it's thoroughly believable that it's more efficient.

After this point you could continue to optimize your run time by accepting approximations:

- choose a set of words of size p you care about, p < m, and just examine the word counts over that domain for a runtime of O(p log p)
- hash individual words to integer indicies, and ignore collisions for a runtime of O(m) (assuming constant time word hashing)

Comment: Nice suggestions, thanks, I will give them a try. Just to be fair: stepping through a `Map` is O(m), not O(m log m). Which is good because I actually have N texts, so complexity is rather O(N m log m + N^2 m)